# functions.logger.warn does not display any level on the Firebase Cloud Functions log

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am using `functions.logger` to log events for my Cloud Functions but I don't understand why the warning level is not taken into consideration on the Firebase console (Cloud Functions logs).

I did a full test with all the available levels and here is the result in my Cloud Function log on the Firebase interface. The warning does not show any level :

[image]

In the documentation they clearly explain that `logger.warn` is considered as an error level log in the Cloud Functions logs but that is not the case in my test :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs

> logger.log() commands have the INFO log level.

> logger.info() commands have the INFO log level.

> logger.warn() commands have the ERROR log level.

> logger.error() commands have the ERROR log level.

> Internal system messages have the DEBUG log level.

It is a big problem for me considering that I really need the warning level for my project, warning level that is well displayed on the Google Cloud Platform console but not on the Firebase Cloud Functions logs.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs#logger-sdk) states that WARNING messages would be logged in Error level  in Firebase Console’s Functions logs.
But after running the below code

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { warn } = require("firebase-functions/lib/logger");
// Attach structured data to the log as the last argument.
 
// Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
//  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
 
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 functions.logger.info("Hello logs!");
 functions.logger.warn();
 response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
 
// Attach structured data to the log as the last argument.
warn("This is a 'WARNING' severity message with some metadata.", {
 key1: 'val1',
 key2: 'val2'
});
```

and deploying it using `firebase deploy –only functions:helloWorld`, the function’s WARNING logs do not appear in any level as rightly informed by you.

I would like you to raise an i[ssue in Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs) /  [issue in GitHub Firebase functions](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions) as the issue is in Firebase Console UI/UX logs severity. To get a faster resolution, please raise the issue in the appropriate component.